# Error when trying to download a file using .net FtpWebRequest class

Tags: c#, ftp

Error message is:

The server returned an address in response to the PASV command that is different than the address to which the FTP connection was made.

I get this message when I try to call GetResponse() method below...
Please help.

Here is my C# code :

FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(feedXmlPath + "\" +
      "testXml", FileMode.Create);

```
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpURL + "/" + zipFileName);

        request.UseBinary = true;

        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password);

        request.KeepAlive = false;

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile;

      FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
      Stream ftpStream = response.GetResponseStream();

      long cl = response.ContentLength;
      int bufferSize = 2048;
      int readCount;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

      readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);


        while (readCount > 0)
      {
          outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
          readCount = ftpStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
      }

      ftpStream.Close();
      outputStream.Close();
      response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of FTPWebRequest isn't permitted for security reasons if you're using NAT. Check out this post on [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=97409&wa=wsignin1.0).

This post on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/661a537b-813f-465c-bdd3-e1df975b7e3c) might be helpful too.

Comment: thanks paul for ur comments...i tried code mentioned in MSDN link above, but no luck still...!

Comment: thanks again paul for ur inputs...am now able to download file after using the following line in my code:

request.Proxy = new WebProxy(myProxyServerIP);

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the Passive value to see which works:

```
    request.UsePassive = false;
```

This may depend on the firewall between the Machines (client and server).

I've noticed if I go through our firewall I need it left at True, otherwise it will return the Exception:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Syntax error, command
>   unrecognized.

However, if I'm behind the firewall (like two machines connecting directly to each other within a data-center) then I need to set it to False, otherwise it will return the Exception:

> The server returned an address in response to the PASV command that is different than the address to which the FTP connection was
>   made.